# Node.js Jasmine helpers onComplete

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I want to set up a callback to run after `jasmine` has completed all tasks.

This is what I've tried:

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jasmine"
  }
  ...
     "jasmine": "^2.8.0"
}
```

**spec/support/jasmine.json**

```
{
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/env.js",
    "helpers/**/*.js"
  ],
  ...
}
```

**spec/helpers/env.js**

```
jasmine.onComplete( () => console.log('yay, done') )
```

but keep on getting errors

```
$ npm test
...
jasmine.onComplete( () => console.log('yay, done') )
    ^
TypeError: jasmine.onComplete is not a function
...
```

Comment: Post your code where you have implemented jasmine

Answer (score 1):

It seems,

You are not going to initialize Jasmine.

```
var Jasmine = require('jasmine');
var jasmine = new Jasmine();
```

Refer [this](https://jasmine.github.io/setup/nodejs.html):

And then this should work:

```
jasmine.onComplete(function(passed) {
  if(passed) {
    console.log('All specs have passed');
  }
  else {
    console.log('At least one spec has failed');
  }
});
```